# Sitecore installation wizard freeze

Tags: installation, sitecore, wizard

I need to install a package on my sitecore instance but for some reason when I click on upload button in the Intallation wizard the whole UI greys out and I can't even upload my package.

Its blocking me from moving forward

Comment: You will likely need to provide additional details (error logs, browser errors in your console) in order to get any meaningful help. As always, make sure you log a ticket with Sitecore support, especially if it's a blocker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this: http://getfishtank.ca/blog/fixing-showmodaldialog-javascript-error-in-chrome-for-sitecore

Sorry for the link-only answer, but this is a known issue with a known resolution path - and it's all summed up there.

Comment: Thanks Mark i was just about to answer here and it works with the solution now